# Run 32Bit API on a x64 System

Tags: .net, com, windows-7-x64, cpu-architecture

How to call a x86 API function from x64 Application when API only supports 32Bit calls.
Example for [CreateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756793%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
    <DllImport("avifil32.dll")> _
    Public Shared Function AVIFileCreateStream(ByVal pfile As IntPtr, ByRef ppavi As IntPtr, ByRef ptr_streaminfo As MyAVISTREAMINFO) As Integer
    End Function
```

**Scenario 1**: x64 Computer + compiled as **x86** application: avifil32.dll called **SUCCESSFULLY**

**Scenario 2:** x64 Computer + compiled as **x64** application: avifil32.dll called **WITH ERROR**

Problem is, that the application also is using x64 hardware driver and I need to compile as x64. Any workaround to use this avifil32.dll would be absolute great.

[image: Access violation with avifil32.dll]

Comment: Any way you can get a x64 dll for avifil? or conversely a x86 hardware driver to use in your application? I don't know of any way to have some pieces of the software be x86 and others to be x64

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new project to your solution and move the API into it. In the project properties, you can specify that it will always compile to x86. Right Click Project > Properties > Compile > Target CPU > Set to x86. This setting is unique for Configuration (debug/release) and Platform (AnyCPU/x64/x86) settings for the solution. Make sure it is set for any you use.

This will let you compile the main project as x64 and the API project as x86.